# How do I customize the Fivestar module?

Tags: rating

I need to customize part of the Fivestar module's output, so that I am able to assign points ( e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

I want the module to sum up and display the total points received by the content or user, and I want to use my own icons in the widgets.

Is this possible?

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: do you want to use the five star module to just get the votes/points?  how are you going to display this sum?  eg, if 5 people give your content each 5 stars do you want to show 25 stars/icons?

Answer (score 3):

Your first two items are settings that can be configured on the Fivestar CCK field's display options. You should read through the [Fivestar Documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/fivestar) thoroughly for instructions on how to set up a rating system.

If you want to use star icons of your own, you can simply override the styling of the Fivestar widget in your theme using CSS. However, if you want to create a star set that can be easily reused across sites, you can follow the instructions for [creating a fivestar widget set](http://drupal.org/node/234391)

Comment: hey thanks...do you also have any documentation or a tutorial, with regards to customization of the fivestar module, to be able to use points. [ 1 2 3 4 5] and so on.

Comment: I have found out a module called [voting rules](http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules), which looks very promising...any guide lines on using it ?

Comment: Can the themes be overrided for fivestar? As in creating own copy of `fivestar.theme.inc` and placing this in one's own theme and overriding the functions. I tried this but my local customisations did not appear, I also tried creating a template file `field--field_five_star--article.tpl` for my `article` content type but again no effect.